# How can I open an srt format in Flet File Picker?

Tags: python, flet

I want to pick an SRT Format file in Flet File Picker. But document said I can only open IMAGE, VIDEO, MEDIA, AUDIO and Custom files. And in front of Custom, they wrote this:
'only files with extensions from allowed_extensions list'

I checked the allowed list, and they wrote this "allowed_extensions

Allow picking files with specified extensions only.
The value of this property is a list of strings, e.g. ["PDF", "SVG", "JPG"]."

How can I use this feature?

First i tried this :

```
on_click = lambda _: filepicker.pick_files(dialog_title = "Choose the subtitle",
file_type = flet.FilePickerFileType.CUSTOM['srt'],
allow_multiple = False))
```

but i got this error:

TypeError: 'FilePickerFileType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to access the srt element of the FilePickerFileType.CUSTOM Enum as a dictionary, but it is actually an enum type.
in the documentation is described:

> FilePickerFileType enum with the following values:
>
> ```
> ANY (default) - any file
> IMAGE
> VIDEO
> MEDIA - VIDEO and IMAGE
> AUDIO
> CUSTOM - only files with extensions from allowed_extensions list
> ```

https://flet.dev/docs/controls/filepicker/

To fix this, you need to change the code to:

```
on_click = lambda _: filepicker.pick_files(dialog_title = "Choose the subtitle",
file_type = flet.FilePickerFileType.CUSTOM,
allowed_extensions = ["srt"],
allow_multiple = False))
```